# Rewrite basic $_GET variable to easy URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I Want to run that website:
www.example.com/generate/myimageweb.php?nickname=Animo2233
from that website:
www.example.com/generate/Animo2233.png

Is it possible in .htacces file?

Please help me.

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow require you to have a basic understanding of the problem that needs to be solved. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182380/233566) for the reason why. See also the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Yes this is possible, it is one of mod_rewrite purposes.

Comment: So if it is possible how to do it... I was searching over 1 hour... And nothing work for me.

Comment: If you have searched for an hour, you must have found something. If you did care to look at the suggestions while typing your question, you would already have solved your problem probably. The first question in the related section, with almost the same title, seems to answer your question just fine. If you have done some research, edit your question and take us on a journey on what you already have searched for and what you have found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this .htaccess into generate directory in your web appp.

```
RewriteEngine On
#if requested file/directory exists do not rewrite!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$        myimageweb.php?nickname=$1       [L]
```